# Calling same view page twice from a controller with different parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First time i called `homepage` for view categories. Now i need to show my images in same `homepage` page.As im calling the same page twice, it showing some elements twice.My question is what is the wise way to call same view page with different parameter from same controller? Thank you.Code is given below for your consideration.

```
<?php 
 class Home extends Controller{

 function index(){



     /*        For categories   */

     $this->load->model('category_model');
    $data['all_categories'] = $this->category_model->all_categories();
    $this->load->view('homepage', $data);


    /* End       For categories   */

    /* Images for homepage*/


    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $data['products'] = $this->home_model->get_all();
    $this->load->view('homepage', $data);

 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Just remove the first `$this->load->view`

Comment: Then how can i show my categories in homepage?how can i send $data array to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first

```
$this->load->view('homepage', $data);
```

Then in the homepage you will be able to access the categories with the variable `$all_categories` and the products with `$products`.

Comment: Thanks lot, it works!! but for curiosity, i didn't send $all_categories to the view page,then how it went to the 'homepage'? I sent only $data,not $all_categories.What is the logic? Thanks again. :)

Comment: `$data` is an array which includes both `all_categories` and `products`. So when you pass `$data` to the view it has both in it.

Comment: (If it works please mark my answer as correct, thanks.)

Comment: Question 1: is $data here working like multidimenssional array?

Question 2: what if i assume first array as $tata,second one is $data,then how could i solve this problem?

sory, i have not such reputation to mark as correct. i am new here. You please mark my question, so that my reputation grows.

Comment: You can mark it as correct, though there may be a time-delay before you can. You should ask any new questions here on Stackoverflow as separate questions.

Comment: I marked your answe as correct. Can you please answer my 2 questions?

Comment: You didn't mark it as correct - you upvoted it. Please mark it as correct, and ask your questions separately in SO.

Comment: i did now u can check it out :( .